# Reaching a dictionary inside a list of dictionaries by key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a `dictionary` that looks like this:

```
{'items': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]}
```

and I'm looking for a way to directly get the inner dictionary with `id = 1`.

Is there a way to reach this other than looping the `list` items and comparing the `id`?

Comment: That might be valid javascript, but python dictionary keys must be quoted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
first_with_id_or_none = \
    next((value for value in dictionary['items'] if value['id'] == 1), None)
```

Answer (score 3):

You will *have* to loop through the list. The good news is is that you can use a generator expression with `next()` to do that looping:

```
yourdict = next(d for d in somedict['items'] if d['id'] == 1)
```

This *can* raise a `StopIteration` exception if there is no such matching dictionary.

Use

```
yourdict = next((d for d in somedict['items'] if d['id'] == 1), None)
```

to return a default instead for that edge-case (here `None` is used, but pick what you need).

Answer (score 2):

Make it into a function:

```
def get_inner_dict_with_value(D, key, value):
    for k, v in D.items():
        for d in v:
            if d.get(key) == value:
                return d 
        else: 
            raise ValueError('the dictionary was not found')
```

With explanation:

```
def get_inner_dict_with_value(D, key, value):
    for k, v in D.items(): # loop the dictionary
        # k = 'items'
        # v = [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]
        for d in v: # gets each inner dictionary
            if d.get(key) == value: # find what you look for
                return d # return it
        else: # none of the inner dictionaries had what you wanted
            raise ValueError('the dictionary was not found') # oh no!
```

Running it:

```
>>> get_inner_dict_with_value({'items': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]}, 'id', 1)
{'id': 1}
```

---

Another method:

```
def get_inner_dict_with_value2(D, key, value):
    try:
        return next((d for l in D.values() for d in l if d.get(key) == value))
    except StopIteration:
        raise ValueError('the dictionary was not found')

>>> get_inner_dict_with_value2({'items': [{'id': 1}, {'id': 2}, {'id': 3}]}, 'id', 1)
{'id': 1}
```